# Need to get rows where combination of two columns both exist and don't exit

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to figure out if it's possible to write a single, set based query to return what I want with data in one single table. The below is just an example, and I need something that could easily work if most (but not all) of combinations 1 to 9 (or 1 to 20 etc) exist.

Table AllCovered has two columns. ID1 and ID2. There are 16 rows in this table, each containing a combination of the numbers 1 to 4 (so 1,1 1,2 1,3 1,4 2,1 .... 4,3 4,4)

Table SomeGaps has the same structure but only has 12 rows, again each row is a combination of 1 to 4, but with some of the combinations missing.

```
SELECT ID1, ID2, COUNT(ID1) as THIS
FROM AllCovered
GROUP BY ID1, ID2
```

- this query returns 16 rows, each combination with 1 in the 3rd column (THIS)

```
SELECT ID1, ID2, COUNT(ID1) as THIS
FROM SomeGaps
GROUP BY ID1, ID2
```

- this returns the 12 rows. **How can I create query that will return 16 rows, of each combination but with 0 in THIS for the combinations that are missing in somegaps?**

```
ID1 ID2 THIS
 1   1   1
 1   2   0 (1,2 combination does NOT exist in SomeGaps)
 1   3   1
 1   4   1
 2   1   1
 2   2   0 (2,2 combination does NOT exist in SomeGaps)
```

Obviously I've tried using a crossjoin to get all combinations of ID1 and ID2 but the COUNT is, as expected, vastly inflated.

Hope this makes sense. Apologies if it's an easy solution, I can't seem to crack it!

Comment: Can you provide a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3) for `AllCovered` and `SomeGaps`?

Comment: I guess I threw a curveball and shouldn't have. AllCovered doesn't exist - it was just an example. My mistake. I've tackled this issue using a different approach. Thanks for the answers and apologies for not explaining it very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by cross-joining all the *distinct* values for the two columns.  Then use `left outer join` and aggregation to get the counts for all combinations:

```
select ac.id1, ac.id2, count(ac.id1) as cnt
from (select distinct id1 from AllCovered) ac1 cross join
     (select distinct id2 from AllCovered) ac2 left join
     AllCovered ac
     on ac.id1 = ac1.id1 and ac.id2 = ac2.id2
group by ac.id1, ac.id2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Apologies for a poor explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably missing something obvious, but I'll take a bite anyway:

```
create table #AllCovered (id1 int, id2 int);
insert #AllCovered values
(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3),(4,4);
create table #gaps (id1 int, id2 int);
insert #gaps values(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,1),(2,4),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(4,1),(4,2),(4,4);


select #AllCovered.id1, #AllCovered.id2,
count(#gaps.id1) as this
from #AllCovered 
left outer join #gaps
on #AllCovered.id1 = #gaps.id1 and #AllCovered.id2 = #gaps.id2
group by #AllCovered.id1, #AllCovered.id2;

drop table #AllCovered, #gaps
```

From your narrative, there are no duplicate combinations of (id1, id2) in neither table, and AllCovered contains all possible combinations -- otherwise will use distinct subqueries and fabricate AllCovered.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Apologies for a poor explanation.